# How to print container id from Docker Compose

Tags: docker

Need to get id's of containers launched by Docker Compose like command 'docker run ...' does (it prints id only). How to do that? Thanks.

Comment: You need to use `docker ps`.

Comment: 'docker ps' is not applicable because Compose is called by CI in my case. I wished Compose to print ID's of containers.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understood what exactly  you are looking for. If you just need to get the container ID

```
sudo docker ps
```

will give that along with some other details.If you need to print only a particular data, then you can make use of  ***docker inspect*** command 
.This displays all the information available in Docker for a given container or image. By default, this will render all results in a JSON array

For example in your case for printing container id only

```
sudo docker inspect --format='{{.Config.Hostname}}' <container_name>
```

or printing the IPaddress

```
sudo docker inspect --format='{{.NetworkSettings.IPAddress}}' <MYSQL cont. ID/container_name>
```

I don't know whether you are asking for this, this may  help any others also

Comment: The problem is that i don't know what is a name of container launched by Compose. I wished Compose to return the ID of container(s) to be used by CI and without manually looking for the name.